# Specify Modified Error Function in form of error functions.

Tags: integration, error-function

I am new to math.stackexchange.com. I am trying to develop a fitting routine and I encounter an integral as follows:
$$\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{erf\left(\frac{t-a}{m}\right)} \cdot t \cdot J_{0}(qt)\mathrm{d}t $$
I have an analytic solution in the following form:
$$ \int_{0}^{x} \mathrm{erf(t)}\cdot t \cdot J_{0}(qt) \mathrm{d}t  $$

Thus, I want your help to express the $\mathrm{erf(\frac{t-a}{m})}$ in form of sum of $\mathrm{erf(x)}$. I can try to handle any extra variables(t) that may emerge during this transformation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Welcome** to the site ! Could you show the analytical solution for the second integral ? Just curious. Is $J_0$ Bessel function ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, the Jo is the Bessel Function. The integral is:
$$ \int_{0}^{x} t \mathrm{erf(t)} J_{0}(qt) \mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{4}\mathrm{e^{-\frac{q^{2}}{8}}} \Bigg(-2I_{0}\Big(\frac{1}{8}\Big)+I_{0}\Big(\frac{q^{2}}{8}\Big)+I_{1}\Big(\frac{q^{2}}{8}\Big)\Bigg)+\frac{\mathrm{e^{-x^{2}}}J_{1}(qx)}{\sqrt{\pi}q}+\frac{x J_{1}(qx) \mathrm{erf(x)}}{q}\\
+\mathrm{e^{-x^{2}}}\sqrt{\pi}\Bigg(-\sqrt{2}\Big(\frac{1}{\pi x}\Big)^{\frac{3}{2}}+\sqrt{2}\Big(\frac{1}{\pi q x}\Big)^{\frac{3}{2}}\Bigg)\cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{4}+x\Big) $$

Comment: How did you get that ? Which CAS did provide such a result ? I tried with $q=1$ and nothing came out.

Comment: I didn't use any CAS, rather used "Gradshteyn, I. S., & Ryzhik, I. M. (2014). Table of Integrals, Series and Products. Arcade" and "W., J. W., & Bois, G. P. (2006). Tables of Indefinite Integrals of Bessel Functions of Integer Order. Mathematics of Computation (Vol. 16)" to find this.

Comment: It's not as easy as you think. Basically, you need to perform a change of variable, but if you shift the argument of your error function, you also shift the argument of the Bessel function, so your formula wouldn't work again. Scaling is not a problem in this case, since it would be absorbed into $q$ and $x$, but the shifting by $a$ is a problem. Maybe we should try deriving a general formula, using the integral definitions of both error and Bessel functions. Not sure if it leads to an exact expression though.

Comment: If I may ask : what kind of fit are you working to use this monster ?

Comment: @YuriyS I agree. It is not easy, that's why asked for help.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I am designing a model for fitting data from my SAXS ion tracks, these tracks have a variety of density fluctuations as we move out from the core to the bulk.

Comment: @Shankar_Dutt, to clarify my comment, I meant that it's quite possible there's no closed form for your case, and it certainly can't be reduced to the more simple integral you provided